# Central Field In Many Electron Atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

I was reading Hartree Self Consistent Field and came across "*Atomic Physics by P. Ewart*" ([PDF](http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~bhasbapat/phy420_files/PE_AP_Notes.pdf)).
In *Central Field Approximation* page 8 it gives the formula for the Hamiltonian in two terms, the Hamiltonian due to central part and the rest of the perturbation as.

> We recall that the hydrogen problem was solved using the symmetry
>    of the central Coulomb field – the $1/r$ potential. This allowed us
>    to separate the radial and angular solutions. In the many electron
>    case, for most of the time, a major part of the repulsion between
>    one electron and the others actstowards the centre. So we replace
>    the $1/r$, hydrogen-like, potential with an effective potential due
>    to the nucleus and the centrally acting part of the $1/r_{ij}$
>    repulsion term. We call this the Central Field $U(r)$. Note it will
>    not be a $1/r$ potential. We now write the Hamiltonian
>    $$\hat{H}=\hat{H}_0+\hat{H}_1 \tag{24}$$
>    $$\text{where }\quad\hat{H}_0
>  =\sum_i\left\{-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla_i^2+U(r_i)\right\} \tag{25}$$
>    $$\text{and }\quad\hat{H}_1
>  =\sum_{i>j}\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r_{ij}}
>  -\sum_i\left\{\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r_i}+U(r_i)\right\}\tag{26}$$

So if you calculate $\hat{H}$ you get
$$\displaystyle \hat {H}= -\sum_i {\frac{h^2}{2m} \nabla^2_i } + \sum_i U{(r_i)} + \displaystyle \sum_{i>j} \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{ij}} - \sum_i U{(r_i)} - \sum_i \frac{Z e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{i}}$$

$$\displaystyle \hat {H}= -\sum_i {\frac{h^2}{2m} \nabla^2_i }+ \displaystyle \sum_{i>j} \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{ij}} - \sum_i \frac{Z e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{i}}$$
**Now when I tried to calculate it.** 
I took potential due to nucleus ( central ) as $$\displaystyle - \sum_i \frac{Z e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{i}} = \sum V_i$$
The electrostatic repulsion as $$\sum_{i>j} \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{ij}} = \sum B_{ij}$$
Some part of $\sum V_i$ is cancelled by central part of $\sum B_{ij} $say that part is $\sum C_i$.
So the non central part left in the system is
$$\sum_{i>j} \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{ij}}- \sum C_i$$

And the central part is $$\sum V_i - \sum C_i= \sum_i U{(r_i)} $$(say)

So the equation for $\displaystyle \hat{H}= \hat {H^0} + \hat {H^1}$ where $\hat {H^0}$ is central part and  $\hat {H^1}$ is non-central part a.k.a perturbation.

put all of above in the equation we get 
 $$\displaystyle \hat {H}= -\sum_j {\frac{h^2}{2m} \nabla^2_i } + \sum_i U{(r_i)} +\sum_{i>j} \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{ij}} - \sum C_i $$

But  $$\sum V_i - \sum C_i= \sum_i U{(r_i)}$$ so

above equation becomes

$$\displaystyle \hat {H}= -\sum_i {\frac{h^2}{2m} \nabla^2_i } + \sum_i U{(r_i)} + \displaystyle \sum_{i>j} \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{ij}} + \sum U{r_i} - \sum V_i$$

$$\displaystyle \hat {H}= -\sum_i {\frac{h^2}{2m} \nabla^2_i }+ \displaystyle \sum_{i>j} \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{ij}} - \sum_i \frac{Z e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{i}}+ 2\sum U{r_i}$$

Where am I calculating wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}$
$\newcommand\grad\nabla$
A small remark before we proceed, we note that the purpose of pertubation theory is to introduce correction hamiltonians of various effects in a bid to recover the "true" hamiltonian which would describe the system fully, which is given by the central potential term in the $H_0$.

With that said, I therefore would conclude that the "true" potential $U\left(\vec{r}\right)$ as presented in equations (25) and (26) not just be one of electrostatic potentials, but also the other terms such as that from $H_2$, the spin-orbit coupling, and other effects (such as hyperfine-coupling).

Even disregarding all these, the following 2 equations you have written are not consistent
$$\begin{align} \sum B_{ij} & = \sum C_i + \left( \sum B_{ij} - \sum C_i \right), \\ \sum U \left( r_i \right) & = \sum V_i - \sum C_i.  \end{align}$$

Full working:
\begin{align} H & = H_0 + H_1 \\ & = \sum_i \left\lbrace -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\grad_i^2 \right\rbrace + \sum_{i>j} \left\lbrace \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{r_{ij}} \right\rbrace + \sum_i \left\lbrace -\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Ze^2}{r_i} \right\rbrace  \\ & = \sum_i \left\lbrace -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\grad_i^2 \right\rbrace + \sum_{i>j} B_{ij} + \sum_i V_i \\ & = \sum_i \left\lbrace -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\grad_i^2 \right\rbrace + \sum C_i + \sum_{i>j} \phi_{ij} + \sum_i V_i \quad \text{where}\ \sum_{i>j} \phi_{ij} = \sum_{i>j} B_{ij} - \sum C_i \\ & = \sum_i \left\lbrace -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\grad_i^2 + C_i + V_i \right\rbrace + \sum_{i>j} \phi_{ij} \\ &= \sum_i \left\lbrace -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\grad_i^2 + U\left(r_i\right) \right\rbrace + \sum_{i>j} \phi_{ij} \\ & = H^0 + H^1. \end{align}

I hope this helped.